# Spring Boot Hibernate's optimistic lock case deadlock in MySQL

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, database-deadlocks, optimistic-locking

I have a question about the deadlock from optimistic lock.
I implemented an simple airline booking system. The database scheme like this:

[image]

In the book flight API, the method will check if the flight is available and get the version number. Then the method will minus 1 from available_seats and check if the version number is same. If not the save() method will throw `ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException` and catch by controller layer. The code is the service layer:

```
    public Ticket bookFlight(Flight flight, long customerId) throws Exception {
        Flight returnedFlight = flightRepository.findFlightByFlightNumberAndFlightDate(flight.getFlightNumber(), flight.getFlightDate());
        if (validFlightIsAvailable(returnedFlight) == false) {
            // A valid flight ticket id should greater than 0.
            // Therefore, ticketId = 0 means the flight is full.
            int fullFlightTicketId = 0;
            log.info("Customer " + customerId + " failed to book the ticket because the flight is full.");
            return new Ticket(fullFlightTicketId);
        } else {
            Ticket newTicket = new Ticket(customerId, returnedFlight.getFlightId(), returnedFlight.getFlightDate());
            if (checkIsDuplicatedBooking(newTicket) == true){
                log.error("The customer (" + customerId + ") already book the ticket for flight " + newTicket.getFlightId());
                throw new ClientException("Customer already booked the ticket in the same flight", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
            }
            returnedFlight.setAvailableSeats(returnedFlight.getAvailableSeats() - 1);
            Flight newFlight = flightRepository.save(returnedFlight);
            if (newFlight == null) {
                log.error("Update flight's available seats error. (flight Id: " +
                        returnedFlight.getFlightId() + "). Rollback all transactions.");
                throw new ServerException("Unknown Server Exception.", HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
            }
            Ticket returnedTicket = ticketRepository.save(newTicket);
            if (returnedTicket != null) {
                log.info("Customer Id: " + customerId + " successfully booked the ticket in flight " + flight.getFlightId());
                return returnedTicket;
            } else {
                log.error("Save new ticket into database error. (Customer Id: " + customerId + ", flight Id: " +
                        returnedFlight.getFlightId() + "). Rollback all transactions.");
                throw new ServerException("Unknown Server Exception.", HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
            }
        }
    }
```

The flight entity is :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "flight")
public class Flight {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy =  GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "flight_id", nullable = false)
    private Long flightId;

    @Column(name = "flight_number", nullable = false)
    private Long flightNumber;

    @Column(name = "flight_date", nullable = false)
    private Date flightDate;

    @Column(name = "available_seats", nullable = false)
    private Integer availableSeats;

    @Column(name = "version")
    @Version
    private int version;

    // Getter and Setter
```

I added a unit test for 50 users and use mockMvc to test the function.

```
@Test
    void bookFlight_Concurrent_Success() throws Exception {
        // Get all flight by Default flight number
        List<Flight> availableFlights = flightService.getAllAvailableFlightsByFlightNumber(defaultFlights.get(0));
        int flightIndex = 3;
        int totalAvailableSeat = availableFlights.get(flightIndex).getAvailableSeats();

        String requestJSON = "{\n" +
                "  \"flightDate\": \"" + availableFlights.get(flightIndex).getFlightDate().toString() + "\",\n" +
                "  \"flightNumber\": " + availableFlights.get(flightIndex).getFlightNumber() + "\n" +
                "}";

        // Set up builders
        List<RequestBuilder> builders = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < defaultCustomerUsernames.size(); i++){
            String jwt = getJWTByUsername(defaultCustomerUsernames.get(i), constants.CUSTOMER_USER_PASSWORD_0);
            RequestBuilder builder = post("/bookFlight").header("Authorization", "Bearer " + jwt).
                    accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(requestJSON).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
            builders.add(builder);
        }

        // Start threads to book flight
        List<Thread> threadList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < defaultCustomerUsernames.size(); i++){
            int finalI0 = i;
            int finalI1 = i;
            Thread thread = new Thread(){
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        System.out.println(this.getName() + ": Start thread " + finalI1);
                        MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(builders.get(finalI0)).andReturn();
                        System.out.println(this.getName() + ": Finish thread " + finalI1);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };


            thread.start();
            threadList.add(thread);
        }

        try{
            for (Thread thread: threadList){
                thread.join();
            }
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Verify the left ticket + booked ticket is full amount
        int bookedTicketNum = ticketRepository.findTicketsByFlightId(availableFlights.get(flightIndex).getFlightId()).size();
        int newAvailableTicket = flightRepository.findFlightByFlightId(availableFlights.get(flightIndex).getFlightId()).getAvailableSeats();
        System.out.println("Booked Ticket Num: " + bookedTicketNum);
        System.out.println("New Available Ticket: " + newAvailableTicket);
        assertEquals(totalAvailableSeat, bookedTicketNum+newAvailableTicket);
    }
```

`beforeAll` and `afterAll` are implemented to generate the default flight and customer user.
The test passed but

```
2020-09-22 21:34:00:667 ERROR [Thread-7] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch [130] : HHH000315: Exception executing batch [java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction], SQL: update flight set available_seats=?, flight_date=?, flight_number=?, version=? where flight_id=? and version=?
2020-09-22 21:34:00:668 ERROR [Thread-7] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper [142] : Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
```

I used  `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` to check deadlock log and get this:

```
=====================================
2020-09-22 21:36:50 0x700001f89000 INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
=====================================
Per second averages calculated from the last 17 seconds
-----------------
BACKGROUND THREAD
-----------------
srv_master_thread loops: 1595 srv_active, 0 srv_shutdown, 22112 srv_idle
srv_master_thread log flush and writes: 0
----------
SEMAPHORES
----------
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: reservation count 2965
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: signal count 44793
RW-shared spins 164384, rounds 166427, OS waits 1899
RW-excl spins 63944, rounds 93238, OS waits 183
RW-sx spins 28152, rounds 88279, OS waits 316
Spin rounds per wait: 1.01 RW-shared, 1.46 RW-excl, 3.14 RW-sx
------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
2020-09-22 21:34:00 0x70000156e000
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 34961, ACTIVE 0 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 7 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 3 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 586, OS thread handle 123145342349312, query id 3508200 localhost 127.0.0.1 root updating
update flight set available_seats=149, flight_date='2020-12-14', flight_number=2, version=7 where flight_id=178360 and version=6

*** (1) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 17 page no 4 n bits 480 index PRIMARY of table `airline_booking_system`.`flight` trx id 34961 lock mode S locks rec but not gap
Record lock, heap no 85 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 7; compact format; info bits 128
 0: len 4; hex 8002b8b8; asc     ;;
 1: len 6; hex 000000008889; asc       ;;
 2: len 7; hex 02000002091880; asc        ;;
 3: len 4; hex 80000002; asc     ;;
 4: len 3; hex 8fc98e; asc    ;;
 5: len 4; hex 80000095; asc     ;;
 6: len 4; hex 80000007; asc     ;;


*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 17 page no 4 n bits 480 index PRIMARY of table `airline_booking_system`.`flight` trx id 34961 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 85 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 7; compact format; info bits 128
 0: len 4; hex 8002b8b8; asc     ;;
 1: len 6; hex 000000008889; asc       ;;
 2: len 7; hex 02000002091880; asc        ;;
 3: len 4; hex 80000002; asc     ;;
 4: len 3; hex 8fc98e; asc    ;;
 5: len 4; hex 80000095; asc     ;;
 6: len 4; hex 80000007; asc     ;;


*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 34959, ACTIVE 0 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 7 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 3 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 591, OS thread handle 123145335984128, query id 3508204 localhost 127.0.0.1 root updating
update flight set available_seats=149, flight_date='2020-12-14', flight_number=2, version=7 where flight_id=178360 and version=6

*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 17 page no 4 n bits 480 index PRIMARY of table `airline_booking_system`.`flight` trx id 34959 lock mode S locks rec but not gap
Record lock, heap no 85 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 7; compact format; info bits 128
 0: len 4; hex 8002b8b8; asc     ;;
 1: len 6; hex 000000008889; asc       ;;
 2: len 7; hex 02000002091880; asc        ;;
 3: len 4; hex 80000002; asc     ;;
 4: len 3; hex 8fc98e; asc    ;;
 5: len 4; hex 80000095; asc     ;;
 6: len 4; hex 80000007; asc     ;;


*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 17 page no 4 n bits 480 index PRIMARY of table `airline_booking_system`.`flight` trx id 34959 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 85 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 7; compact format; info bits 128
 0: len 4; hex 8002b8b8; asc     ;;
 1: len 6; hex 000000008889; asc       ;;
 2: len 7; hex 02000002091880; asc        ;;
 3: len 4; hex 80000002; asc     ;;
 4: len 3; hex 8fc98e; asc    ;;
 5: len 4; hex 80000095; asc     ;;
 6: len 4; hex 80000007; asc     ;;

*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (2)
------------
TRANSACTIONS
------------
Trx id counter 35089
Purge done for trx's n:o < 35089 undo n:o < 0 state: running but idle
History list length 0
LIST OF TRANSACTIONS FOR EACH SESSION:
---TRANSACTION 422038541902072, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 422038541902912, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 422038541901232, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 422038541897872, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 422038541899552, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 422038541898712, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 422038541897032, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 422038541896192, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 422038541895352, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
--------
FILE I/O
--------
I/O thread 0 state: waiting for i/o request (insert buffer thread)
I/O thread 1 state: waiting for i/o request (log thread)
I/O thread 2 state: waiting for i/o request (read thread)
I/O thread 3 state: waiting for i/o request (read thread)
I/O thread 4 state: waiting for i/o request (read thread)
I/O thread 5 state: waiting for i/o request (read thread)
I/O thread 6 state: waiting for i/o request (write thread)
I/O thread 7 state: waiting for i/o request (write thread)
I/O thread 8 state: waiting for i/o request (write thread)
I/O thread 9 state: waiting for i/o request (write thread)
Pending normal aio reads: [0, 0, 0, 0] , aio writes: [0, 0, 0, 0] ,
 ibuf aio reads:, log i/o's:, sync i/o's:
Pending flushes (fsync) log: 0; buffer pool: 1
1276 OS file reads, 982454 OS file writes, 737797 OS fsyncs
0.00 reads/s, 0 avg bytes/read, 0.00 writes/s, 0.00 fsyncs/s
-------------------------------------
INSERT BUFFER AND ADAPTIVE HASH INDEX
-------------------------------------
Ibuf: size 1, free list len 0, seg size 2, 0 merges
merged operations:
 insert 0, delete mark 0, delete 0
discarded operations:
 insert 0, delete mark 0, delete 0
Hash table size 34679, node heap has 1 buffer(s)
Hash table size 34679, node heap has 2 buffer(s)
Hash table size 34679, node heap has 2 buffer(s)
Hash table size 34679, node heap has 1 buffer(s)
Hash table size 34679, node heap has 1 buffer(s)
Hash table size 34679, node heap has 1 buffer(s)
Hash table size 34679, node heap has 1 buffer(s)
Hash table size 34679, node heap has 4 buffer(s)
0.00 hash searches/s, 0.00 non-hash searches/s
---
LOG
---
Log sequence number          1793856320
Log buffer assigned up to    1793856320
Log buffer completed up to   1793856320
Log written up to            1793856320
Log flushed up to            1793856320
Added dirty pages up to      1793856320
Pages flushed up to          1793856320
Last checkpoint at           1793856320
937447 log i/o's done, 0.00 log i/o's/second
----------------------
BUFFER POOL AND MEMORY
----------------------
Total large memory allocated 137363456
Dictionary memory allocated 476872
Buffer pool size   8191
Free buffers       5484
Database pages     2694
Old database pages 982
Modified db pages  0
Pending reads      0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 4, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 1241, created 1453, written 34817
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
No buffer pool page gets since the last printout
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 2694, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
--------------
ROW OPERATIONS
--------------
0 queries inside InnoDB, 0 queries in queue
0 read views open inside InnoDB
Process ID=2483, Main thread ID=0x70000177a000 , state=sleeping
Number of rows inserted 2692764, updated 1168, deleted 1168363, read 1256843
0.00 inserts/s, 0.00 updates/s, 0.00 deletes/s, 0.00 reads/s
Number of system rows inserted 22, updated 377, deleted 20, read 13121
0.00 inserts/s, 0.00 updates/s, 0.00 deletes/s, 0.00 reads/s
----------------------------
END OF INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
============================
```

I think two update transaction cause this issue.
I tried to manual debug, and still can use other tools update the row after `Flight newFlight = flightRepository.save(returnedFlight);`
But, I cannot update the row after `Ticket returnedTicket = ticketRepository.save(newTicket);`

The deadlock log:

```
=====================================
2020-09-22 21:41:23 0x700001f89000 INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
=====================================
Per second averages calculated from the last 29 seconds
-----------------
BACKGROUND THREAD
-----------------
srv_master_thread loops: 1597 srv_active, 0 srv_shutdown, 22382 srv_idle
srv_master_thread log flush and writes: 0
----------
SEMAPHORES
----------
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: reservation count 2965
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: signal count 44793
RW-shared spins 164384, rounds 166427, OS waits 1899
RW-excl spins 63944, rounds 93238, OS waits 183
RW-sx spins 28152, rounds 88279, OS waits 316
Spin rounds per wait: 1.01 RW-shared, 1.46 RW-excl, 3.14 RW-sx
------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
2020-09-22 21:41:17 0x70000156e000
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 35092, ACTIVE 24 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 2 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 1 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 8, OS thread handle 123145333862400, query id 3508825 localhost 127.0.0.1 root updating
/* ApplicationName=DataGrip 2020.2.2 */ UPDATE airline_booking_system.flight t SET t.version = 12 WHERE t.flight_id = 173431

*** (1) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 17 page no 4 n bits 480 index PRIMARY of table `airline_booking_system`.`flight` trx id 35092 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 4 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 7; compact format; info bits 128
 0: len 4; hex 8002a577; asc    w;;
 1: len 6; hex 000000008911; asc       ;;
 2: len 7; hex 020000016c0c77; asc     l w;;
 3: len 4; hex 80000373; asc    s;;
 4: len 3; hex 8fc938; asc   8;;
 5: len 4; hex 80000096; asc     ;;
 6: len 4; hex 8000000b; asc     ;;


*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 17 page no 4 n bits 480 index PRIMARY of table `airline_booking_system`.`flight` trx id 35092 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 4 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 7; compact format; info bits 128
 0: len 4; hex 8002a577; asc    w;;
 1: len 6; hex 000000008911; asc       ;;
 2: len 7; hex 020000016c0c77; asc     l w;;
 3: len 4; hex 80000373; asc    s;;
 4: len 3; hex 8fc938; asc   8;;
 5: len 4; hex 80000096; asc     ;;
 6: len 4; hex 8000000b; asc     ;;


*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 35091, ACTIVE 41 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 7 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 3 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 599, OS thread handle 123145336287232, query id 3508827 localhost 127.0.0.1 root updating
update flight set available_seats=149, flight_date='2020-09-24', flight_number=883, version=11 where flight_id=173431 and version=10

*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 17 page no 4 n bits 480 index PRIMARY of table `airline_booking_system`.`flight` trx id 35091 lock mode S locks rec but not gap
Record lock, heap no 4 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 7; compact format; info bits 128
 0: len 4; hex 8002a577; asc    w;;
 1: len 6; hex 000000008911; asc       ;;
 2: len 7; hex 020000016c0c77; asc     l w;;
 3: len 4; hex 80000373; asc    s;;
 4: len 3; hex 8fc938; asc   8;;
 5: len 4; hex 80000096; asc     ;;
 6: len 4; hex 8000000b; asc     ;;


*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 17 page no 4 n bits 480 index PRIMARY of table `airline_booking_system`.`flight` trx id 35091 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 4 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 7; compact format; info bits 128
 0: len 4; hex 8002a577; asc    w;;
 1: len 6; hex 000000008911; asc       ;;
 2: len 7; hex 020000016c0c77; asc     l w;;
 3: len 4; hex 80000373; asc    s;;
 4: len 3; hex 8fc938; asc   8;;
 5: len 4; hex 80000096; asc     ;;
 6: len 4; hex 8000000b; asc     ;;

*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (1)
------------
TRANSACTIONS
------------
Trx id counter 35093
Purge done for trx's n:o < 35091 undo n:o < 0 state: running but idle
History list length 1
LIST OF TRANSACTIONS FOR EACH SESSION:
---TRANSACTION 422038541900392, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 422038541902072, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 422038541902912, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 422038541901232, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 422038541897872, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 422038541899552, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 422038541898712, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 422038541897032, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 422038541896192, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 422038541895352, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
--------
FILE I/O
--------
I/O thread 0 state: waiting for i/o request (insert buffer thread)
I/O thread 1 state: waiting for i/o request (log thread)
I/O thread 2 state: waiting for i/o request (read thread)
I/O thread 3 state: waiting for i/o request (read thread)
I/O thread 4 state: waiting for i/o request (read thread)
I/O thread 5 state: waiting for i/o request (read thread)
I/O thread 6 state: waiting for i/o request (write thread)
I/O thread 7 state: waiting for i/o request (write thread)
I/O thread 8 state: waiting for i/o request (write thread)
I/O thread 9 state: waiting for i/o request (write thread)
Pending normal aio reads: [0, 0, 0, 0] , aio writes: [0, 0, 0, 0] ,
 ibuf aio reads:, log i/o's:, sync i/o's:
Pending flushes (fsync) log: 0; buffer pool: 1
1276 OS file reads, 982489 OS file writes, 737827 OS fsyncs
0.00 reads/s, 0 avg bytes/read, 0.24 writes/s, 0.17 fsyncs/s
-------------------------------------
INSERT BUFFER AND ADAPTIVE HASH INDEX
-------------------------------------
Ibuf: size 1, free list len 0, seg size 2, 0 merges
merged operations:
 insert 0, delete mark 0, delete 0
discarded operations:
 insert 0, delete mark 0, delete 0
Hash table size 34679, node heap has 1 buffer(s)
Hash table size 34679, node heap has 2 buffer(s)
Hash table size 34679, node heap has 2 buffer(s)
Hash table size 34679, node heap has 1 buffer(s)
Hash table size 34679, node heap has 1 buffer(s)
Hash table size 34679, node heap has 1 buffer(s)
Hash table size 34679, node heap has 1 buffer(s)
Hash table size 34679, node heap has 4 buffer(s)
0.03 hash searches/s, 0.10 non-hash searches/s
---
LOG
---
Log sequence number          1793857089
Log buffer assigned up to    1793857089
Log buffer completed up to   1793857089
Log written up to            1793857089
Log flushed up to            1793857089
Added dirty pages up to      1793857089
Pages flushed up to          1793857089
Last checkpoint at           1793857089
937456 log i/o's done, 0.03 log i/o's/second
----------------------
BUFFER POOL AND MEMORY
----------------------
Total large memory allocated 137363456
Dictionary memory allocated 476872
Buffer pool size   8191
Free buffers       5484
Database pages     2694
Old database pages 982
Modified db pages  0
Pending reads      0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 4, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 1241, created 1453, written 34832
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 2694, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
--------------
ROW OPERATIONS
--------------
0 queries inside InnoDB, 0 queries in queue
0 read views open inside InnoDB
Process ID=2483, Main thread ID=0x70000177a000 , state=sleeping
Number of rows inserted 2692765, updated 1169, deleted 1168363, read 1256855
0.00 inserts/s, 0.00 updates/s, 0.00 deletes/s, 0.03 reads/s
Number of system rows inserted 22, updated 377, deleted 20, read 13205
0.00 inserts/s, 0.00 updates/s, 0.00 deletes/s, 0.00 reads/s
----------------------------
END OF INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
============================
```

If anyone can help me? I tried Pessimistic Lock and no issue.

Comment: Look at your two transations that deadlock. They are identical. A [deadlock is a friend](https://www.percona.com/blog/2020/07/07/mysql-deadlocks-are-our-friends/), that tell our application that we need to do something.

Comment: Available seats is a bad contruct that is going to deadlock easily. Its probably better to store  a maximum number of seats for the flight and use the bookings to determine gaps/full status.

Comment: I tried to change the save function to saveAndFlush, then I do not see the deadlock again.

Comment: Handling dead locks is a better idea. Two booking for the same seat could happen at the same time. Its not until that transaction commits that you'll find out. Show the user an error  in a business logical way, 'seat taken, choose another'